# Left Justify Logo Text and Center Nav Bar in the same line

Tags: html, css, nav

I am trying to left align some text and center align another set of text.

This is a snippet of my HTML:

```
    <div class="header-inner">

        <div class="logo">
            <a href="">Puremedia.</a>
        </div>

        <nav id="nav-wrap">
            <ul id="nav" class="nav">
                <li class="current"><a href="">Home.</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Stores.</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Solutions.</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About Us.</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Volunteer With Us.</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav> <!-- /nav-wrap -->

    </div> <!-- /header-inner -->
```

This is a snippet of my CSS:

```
/* g. Header Styles
/* =================================================================== */
header {
    height: 72px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 990;
    background: #0e1015;
    text-align: center;
}
header .logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
header .logo a {
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    width: 126px;
    height: 12px;
    font-family: "raleway-SemiBold", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
}



/* navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* nav-wrap */
#nav-wrap {
    font: 11px "raleway-heavy", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul#nav li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    height: 72px;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul#nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 17px 12px;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c0cdd1;
}
ul#nav li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
ul#nav li a:active {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
ul#nav li.current a {
    background: #209907;
    color: white;
}
```

My full code can be found here: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/guJBhxkzAK4fTTasEEQX

Currently, the Change ASEAN and the NAV bar items are all center aligned. However, what I am trying to do is to have the Change ASEAN all the way to the left and the NAV bar items in the center. How do I do this?

For Now my header looks like this:
[image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

I achieved this by doing a manual positioning using padding. However, I am not sure if the alignment would still look like this when people with smaller/larger screens open the website. Therefore, I was thinking of using text-align or float. However, it seems that I can only text-align/float the logo and NAV bar as a whole. Meaning center everything or left justify everything. Is there a  way to left justify the logo and center the NAV bar?

Comment: I think you should have a look at flexbox for layouts, unless you want to support some browsers before 2012. https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your `header .logo` css with below will give you desire result.

```
header .logo {
    float: left;
    line-height: 72px;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```css
/* Body
---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

body {
  background: #0e1015;
  font: 15px/30px "merriweather-regular", serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #0e1015;
}


/* Typography
--------------------------------------------------------------------- */

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "raleway-bold", sans-serif;
  color: #252525;
  font-style: normal;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  margin: 18px 0 15px;
}

h1 a,
h2 a,
h3 a,
h4 a,
h5 a,
h6 a {
  font-weight: inherit;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin-top: 0;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p {
  margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

p img {
  margin: 0;
}

p.lead {
  font: 17px/33px "merriweather-light", serif;
  color: #707273;
}

strong,
b {
  font: 15px/30px "merriweather-bold", serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

small {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: inherit;
}


/* Lists
--------------------------------------------------------------------- */

ul {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

ul {
  list-style: disc;
  margin-left: 17px;
}


/* 
/* g. Header Styles
/* =================================================================== */

header {
  height: 72px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 990;
  background: #0e1015;
  text-align: center;
}

header .logo {
  float: left;
  line-height: 72px;
  margin: 15px;
}

header .logo a {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  width: 126px;
  height: 12px;
  font-family: "raleway-SemiBold", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------- */


/* nav-wrap */

#nav-wrap {
  font: 11px "raleway-heavy", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul#nav li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  height: 72px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul#nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 17px 12px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c0cdd1;
}

ul#nav li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

ul#nav li a:active {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

ul#nav li.current a {
  background: #209907;
  color: white;
}


/* 
/* i. Footer Styles
/* =================================================================== */

footer {
  padding-top: 36px;
  padding-bottom: 42px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  color: #3C4142;
}

footer a,
footer a:visited {
  color: #a43b0a;
}

footer a:hover,
footer a:focus {
  color: white;
}

footer h3 {
  font: 13px/24px "raleway-bold", sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

footer p {
  margin: 12px 0;
}

footer .footer-about {
  padding-right: 60px;
}

footer .right-cols .columns {
  width: 50%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

footer ul {
  margin: 12px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

footer ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
}

footer ul li a,
footer ul li a:visited {
  color: #3C4142;
}

footer .copyright {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px 18px 6px 18px;
  clear: both;
}


/* back to top */

footer #go-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 900;
  display: none;
}

footer #go-top a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  background: #d44d0d;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font: 12px/24px "raleway-heavy", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

footer #go-top a span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

footer #go-top a:hover {
  background: #faec09;
  color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<body class="homepage">


  <!-- Header
   =================================================== -->
  <header id="main-header">

    <div class="header-inner">

      <div class="logo">
        <a href="">Change ASEAN.</a>
      </div>

      <nav id="nav-wrap">
        <ul id="nav" class="nav">
          <li class="current"><a href="">Home.</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Stores.</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Solutions.</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About Us.</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Volunteer With Us.</a></li>
        </ul>

      </nav>
      <!-- /nav-wrap -->

    </div>
    <!-- /header-inner -->

  </header>


  <!-- Footer
   ================================================== -->
  <footer></footer>
  <!-- /footer -->

</body>
```

Comment: We're currently in 2019, why still use floats for layouts?

Comment: @Tom you are right we can use flex and grid and all but depend on his requirement and what he code so far float was good option for him.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `float: left` on the logo and then add an @media query for smaller screens that sets `float: none` or `display: none` to prevent clipping?